# Expo MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({album:album}) is not returning album - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, native

I am using Expo MediaLibrary to get videos from a specific folder and I am facing this problem.

MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync() shows there are no media inside an album. while there are media inside the folder.

Code:

```
  let album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync("GrabTube")
  console.log(album )
  let assets = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({album:album })
  console.log(assets)
```

response:

```
Object {
  "assetCount": 1,
  "id": "876214992",
  "title": "GrabTube",
}
Object {
  "assets": Array [],
  "endCursor": "0",
  "hasNextPage": false,
  "totalCount": 0,
}
```

In the first console.log, it shows there is one item/asset inside the folder. But as shown inside the second console.log it shows the folder is empty.

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it's necessary to define the mediaType even when you have already defined the album...

to me the solution was change from :

```
let assets = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({album:album })
```

to:

```
let assets = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({album:album, mediaType:'audio' })
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have solved this problem and my solution was similar. I will accept it as the answer.